# Looping through lists within lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I read somewhere that by doing

```
var = [12,34]
a = var
b = a
```

by doing this 'a' and 'v' and 'b' refer to the same list and changes in 'a' add changes to 'b' and 'var' as well,
so when we do

```
for i in [some list x, some list y]]:
```

does i refer to both list 'x' and list 'y' in the end or only list 'y'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if `x` and `y` are the same object, the loop variable will refer to the same object as well, as can be demonstrated by this code:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x

for i in [x, y]:
   ...

i.append(4)
print(x)
print(y)
```

In other words, name bindings in `for`-loops behave just like regular Python assignments.

Answer (score 0):

At the end **i** refer only to list **y**.
Here is example:

```
for i in [[1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c']]:
    pass
print(i)
```

The result is:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: This is true for **your** example, that is however not the same for what the OP mentions. Instead of putting the lists in the for directly, try adding the code of the question before the for loop and loop over `[a, b]`